# Rule that checks artifact does not work in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

when I try to check an artifact path this rule does not work:

```
.upload_env_secrets: &upload_env_secrets |
  vault kv put /patha/pathb/pathc @$ARTIFACT_PATH/env.json

    deploy-secrets-app:
      extends: .deploy-secrets
      stage: Provision
      rules:
        - exists:
            - $ARTIFACT_PATH/env.json
      needs:
        - job: set-deployment_id
          optional: true
        - pipeline: $PIPELINE_ID
          job: build-artifact
      script:
        - *upload_env_secrets
```

The rule: exists keyword do not works...

Comment: Can you define "does not work"? do you get an error? does the job not get created? if you try with a simple task that doesnt have the exists rule and the script just lists the artifact_paths env.json do you see it existing? where is this var being set? is this an actual artifact that will be loaded by gitlabs runner?

Comment: the path exists I have listed the files and it exists I did a cat to show the content and it works, but the rule doesn't jump and the job is not shown in the pipeline

Comment: But where is the source of the file coming from? is it being loaded from an actual artifact from a previous stage?

Comment: Yes! the artifact comes from other job

Comment: My understanding from reading the docs and how the gitlab runner works. Is that `rules:exists` can only be used for files that are in the repository. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rulesexists states `Use exists to run a job when certain files exist in the repository.`. I dont think that would inclide artifacts as they are only loaded once the job is running and the job then loads them in. So in my view/understanding you couldnt use a rules condition like this on an artifact. I have not tested that so i could be wrong. just my personal view based on the docs and how i understand things.

Comment: I just found this:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/386595

May I can't do that...

Comment: @ChrisDoyle is correct. `rules:` are processed at the time the pipeline is created and is evaluated on the GitLab server before any job in the pipeline starts. Therefore, `rules:` (including `rules:exists:`) cannot be based on files you expect to be present from an artifact download, or any condition that occurs after the pipeline is created.

Comment: I just solved it downloading the artifact, how @ChrisDoyle told me. Thanks